# Perl, Count characters and break at the end of a word

Tags: perl

I'm trying to break on 300 characters, which it does fine but I don’t want it to break in the middle of a word. I would like to find either the end of a word or on the next available whitespace. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
foreach (@$comp) {
    my $c = $_;
    $c->{reviews} = ($c->{reviews} - 1);
    my $stars;
    if($c->{reviews} == 0) {
        $stars = 0;
    } else {
        $stars = int($c->{reviews_total} / $c->{reviews});
    } 
    $c->{stars} = $stars; 

    if($c->{title}) { 
        $c->{name} = $c->{title}; 
        $c->{event} = "FOO"; 
    }
    $c->{description} =~ s/BREAK//g; 

    my (@desc) = split(//, $c->{description});   

    my $adesc;
    my $rowc = 0;
    my $count = 0;

    while($count < 300 ) {
         $adesc .= @desc[$count];
         $rowc++;
         $count++;
    }

    $c->{description} = $adesc;= '...';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's see what [`perldoc perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-tabs-in-a-string%3f) has to say:

> **How do I reformat a paragraph?**
>
> Use `Text::Wrap` (part of the standard Perl distribution):
>
> ```
> use Text::Wrap;
> print wrap("\t", '  ', @paragraphs);
> ```
>
> The paragraphs you give to `Text::Wrap` should not contain embedded
>   newlines. `Text::Wrap` doesn't justify the lines (flush-right).

---

But what if you don't like it?

Visit [`CPAN`](https://metacpan.org)

- [`Text::Wrap::Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aWrap%3a%3aSmart)

  ```
  use Text::Wrap::Smart 'wrap_smart';
  use feature 'say';

  my $text = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' x 500;

  my $options = { 
                  no_split     => 1,   # Activates 'fuzzy matching'
                  max_msg_size => 300,
                };

  say for wrap_smart( $text, $options );
  ```
- [`Text::Flow::Wrap`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aFlow%3a%3aWrap)
- [`Text::Reform`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aReform)
- [`Unicode::LineBreak`](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aLineBreak)

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
my $str = q!A very long string to be wrapped on whitespace!;
my $len = 15; #for test. In your case, let $len=300
my @l = grep{s/^\s+//;$_ ne ''}split(/(.{1,$len})(?=\s)/, $str);
dump@l;
```

**output:**

```
("A very long", "string to be", "wrapped on", "whitespace")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$str = "my big string blah blah...";
for ( $i = 300; substr( $x, $i, 1 ) =~ /\w/; $i++ ) { };
$str = substr( $str, 0, $i );
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I think in line 2 there you want `$x` to be `$str`? also, since this is a rather "golf-like" approach, maybe you could help OP by giving some explanation of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nwE 'say for m/(.{0,75} )/g' textsample2.txt
HAMLET: To be, or not to be--that is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in
the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune Or to take
...
```

Works like a charm. Unless you have extremely long words in your text, just tweak the numbers.

You'll have to remove all old linebreaks first, of course. So, something like:

```
sub wrap_text {
    my ($text, $len) = @_;
    $text =~ s/[\r\n]+//g;  # yeah, removing \r while at it
    return ( $text =~ m/(.{0,$len} )/g );
}
```

And then:

```
say for wrap_text($text, 300);
```